# Python datatype that includes uncertainty/error bars?

Tags: python, math, types, statistics, uncertainty

Is there a python datatype that includes numerical error bars?

For example,

```
: a = 3.00 ± 0.100
: b = 4.00 ± 0.100
: b + a
>> 7.00 ± 0.141
```

Where `√(0.1^2 + 0.1^2) = 0.141`

I figured since imaginary numbers already exist in a form something like this `a= 3 + j4`, maybe there is a module that handles error analysis for you as well.  (I suppose it's complicated by the fact that the + & - uncertainties need not be equal.)

Comment: Did you try to google? First hit: https://pythonhosted.org/uncertainties/user_guide.html

Comment: your google-fu is clearly a few belts beyond my own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. There is a package called uncertainties.
Install it: `sudo pip install uncertainties`

Example:

```
        from uncertainties import ufloat_fromstr
        x = ufloat_fromstr("0.20+/-0.01")
        square = x**2
        print square
```

For more info: https://pythonhosted.org/uncertainties/user_guide.html